# Custom Kernel for VMWare

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm building a custom kernel to run in a VMWare guest. The idea is to disable all of the drivers, security features, debugging, and other non-essential features. I have a few questions:

1) Is this likely to result in significant performance improvements?

2) Is there an easier way to do this besides going through menuconfig and unchecking a ton of stuff?

3) Has someone else already done this, saving me time?

Comment: 1) No. 2) No. 3) You're already wasting your time trying.  Really.  Consider changing things only when you can _measure_ the effects. And disable security features only when you fully understand the risks.

Comment: I agree about the security, but I'm familiar with the risk. Also, the effects can be measured by benchmarking the boot process and other operations.

Comment: Benchmarking boot and measuring the effects of changing the kernel are very different concepts.  Which I suspect is why you asked here in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel includes only critical drivers which are essential for it to work. A bunch of other drivers exist but are provided as external modules and loaded at runtime only if necessary.

Disabling security features is a very bad idea.

As for disabling debugging, I don't know how much space you'll save with that but it will be hardly worth the effort.

You might want to have a look at [Tiny Core Linux](http://tinycorelinux.net/) or the [Linux Kernel Tinification](https://tiny.wiki.kernel.org/) project which might provide what you're looking for.

Comment: And even then, those small kernels wont probably be useful as they are; you do not want to cut support for paravirtualization of virtual NICs and disks.

Comment: The Linux kernel contains a ton of drivers for rare and archaic hardware, but I think `make tinyconfig` is what I'm looking for. That was in the Linux Kernel Tinification link.